# Filter Function - Type mismatch issue with strings

Tags: vba, excel

I got an issue with type mismatch when using the filter function. I pass a string to guess and everything except that if statement works fine. Anyone knows what the issue can be?

```
Private Function perform_word(guess As String)

Dim area As Range
Dim hold_split() As String
Dim check_sum As String
Dim rng As String


Set area = Range("A1:G7")

ReDim hold_split(1 To Len(guess))

For i = 1 To Len(guess)
    hold_split(i) = Mid(guess, i, 1)
Next i

For i = 1 To area.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To area.Columns.Count
    rng = area(i, j).Value
    If rng = Filter(hold_split, rng) Then           <<<<---- type mismatch here :(

    End If
    Next j
Next i

If check_sum = guess Then
    Debug.Print check_sum
End If
perform_word = hold_split
End Function
```

Comment: The return value of the [`Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278418(v=office.14).aspx) function is an array, not a string. You're assigning the return value to `rng`, which is a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of the [`Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278418(v=office.14).aspx) function is an array, not a string.

You're assigning the return value to `rng`, which is a String.